# Calling interface's default method when superclass has private method

Tags: java, interface, default-method, name-conflict

Consider the code below.

```
interface I {
    default Number f() {
        return 0;
    }
}

class A {
    private Number f() { // if Number is replaced with other type, all will work fine
        return 1;
    }
}

class B extends A implements I {
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new B().f());
    }
}
```

This program yields an `IllegalAccessError`.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class tasks.a1.Main tried to access private method 'java.lang.Number tasks.a1.A.f()' (tasks.a1.Main and tasks.a1.A are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at tasks.a1.Main.main(Sub.java:20)
```

But if you replace the return value of `A.f()` with `Integer` or `Object`, no error will occur and the default method will be executed.

Why in the code snippet above `IllegalAccessError` occurs but after the described modification all works fine?

Both methods in the question [Calling default method in interface when having conflict with private method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49610855/calling-default-method-in-interface-when-having-conflict-with-private-method) have the same return type (namely, `void`), but I'm wondering why the error disappears after making return types different.

Comment: do you understand why private is private?

Comment: @Turing85 yeah, I already realized that :) my bad... will remove the comments

Comment: @Eugene so... re-close again?

Comment: @Turing85 this is still weird. if you make those classes static (as I previously did), the code fails under `jdk-8`, but works under `jdk-13` and up. I can only assume that `JEP 181` has something to do with this, will dig further

Comment: @Eugene [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231552/room-for-turing85-and-eugene)?